# Formatting and Trimming Datatable column

Tags: c#

I have datatable with date column, which is storing datetime format from Excel sheet in the form:

```
2014-05-22 00:00:00
```

I want this column only to store date not time in diff format:

```
22-05-2014
```

How can I do this using C# datatable?

Comment: A `DateTime` always has a time part. Do you want to store a string instead(`dt.ToShortDateString()`)? How do you create the excel file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store it like a string using the `ToShortDateString()` method of your datetime. Or you could use the method `ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`.